# How does one feed graph optimization problems into Python's anneal function in SciPy?

Tags: python, optimization, graphs, scipy

I am interested in graph problems like 2-color, max-clique, stable sets, etc but the documentation for scipy.optimize.anneal seems to be for ordinary functions. How would one apply this library towards graph formulations?

Comment: That's fairly open ended. Can you say more about your requirements and what you have tried?

Comment: With many LP (or MILP) solvers, you can easily add the convex and the constraints. For example, in scipy.optimize.anneal I could try f(x) = sum(x) as simply summing the input, e.g. in the case of a Graph's nodes. But two things are not clear: How do we pass in graphs to begin with and how do we impose further constraints, i.e. the requirement that every connected edge must contain different node colors?